# Merge dynamic arrays without keys

Tags: php, yii2

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = ['label' => 'FirstButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']];
$array2 = ['label' => 'SecondButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']];
```

What I want to do, is to merge these arrays like this:

```
$array3 = [$array1, array2];
```

So example result whould be like this:

```
$array3 = [
    ['label' => 'FirstButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']], 
    ['label' => 'SecondButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']]
];
```

How can I do that? I'm using Yii2 framework, and bootstrap widget ButtonGroup. ButtonGroup widget example:

```
<?php
    echo ButtonGroup::widget([
            'buttons' => [
                ['label' => 'FirstButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']],
                ['label' => 'SecondButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']]
            ],
            'options' => ['class' => 'float-right']
        ]);
?>
```

The reason I need to merge these arrays like this is because my ButtonGroup is dynamic, and in view file I want to use variable from controller $buttonGroup:

```
<?php
    echo ButtonGroup::widget([
            'buttons' => [$buttonGroup],
            'options' => ['class' => 'float-right']
        ]);
?>
```

**Update** In controller I have this:

```
$buttonGroups = [];
foreach($client as $key => $value) {
    $buttonGroups[] = ['label' => $client[$key], 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']];
}
```

where  `$client[$key]` is the name of the button. So my arrays are dynamic and I can't just merge arrays like this:

```
$array3 = array($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but doesn't `$buttonGroups` after the foreach loop in the controller have exactly the structure you're looking for?

Comment: It has structure like this:
[0] => array1;
[1] => array2;
But ButtonGroup need [array1, array2], without keys. What format buttonGroup accepts showed in ButtonGroup example above.

Comment: `$x=[$array1, $array2]` results in an array having the keys `0` and `1` exactly as does `$x=array($array1, $array2)` or `$x=array(0=>$array1, 1=>$array2)` or `$x = array(); $x[] = $array1; $x[] = $array2;` - they are indistinguishable. [a1,a2] is just syntactic sugar, so developers have to type less - but it results in the same, exactly the same internal representation.

Comment: So how can I make from this syntax `$x = [[0] => $a1, [1] => $a2]` to this syntax `$x = [$a1, $a2]` ? Because ButtonGroup accepts only this syntax `$x = [$a1, $a2]`

Comment: You do nothing....because it's already there.... The function/method accepts an array with a specific structure; you already have that structure - regardless of whether in the source code this structure has been created via `array(0=>x, 1=>y)` or `[x,y]`; it doesn't matter; at runtime both are indistinguishable/the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
$array3 = array( $array1, $array2 );
```

and then :

```
 echo ButtonGroup::widget([
            'buttons' => $array3,
            'options' => ['class' => 'float-right']
        ]);
```

**Update:**

```
[
    ['label' => 'FirstButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']],
    ['label' => 'SecondButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']]
]
```

is simply another definition style of (since PHP5.4):

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

**Source**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
array(
    array('label' => 'FirstButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button']),
    array('label' => 'SecondButton', 'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'type' => 'button'])
)
```

so you should be able to use directly:

```
<?php
    echo ButtonGroup::widget([
            'buttons' => $buttonGroups,
            'options' => ['class' => 'float-right']
        ]);
?>
```

Comment: I have dynamic arrays so I can't just use $array3 = array( $array1, $array2 );

Comment: Thank you Taha Paksu for your answer, you were right. I read about array from source you gave, and carefully checked my code. Then I copied your given code and it worked, so that was my mistake that I used `'buttons' => [$buttonGroups],` insted of `'buttons' => $buttonGroups,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line using the `array_merge()` method.

Example:

```
echo ButtonGroup::widget([
        'buttons' => array_merge($array1, array2),
        'options' => ['class' => 'float-right']
    ]);
```